# verilogでのカウントについて

Tags: verilog

アルテラのFPGA MAX10でverilogで書いておりますが、ちょっとわからないことがあり質問いたします。
早いクロック(Clock1)と遅いクロック(Clock2)があり、早いクロックでクロックをカウントし、
遅いクロックの立ち上がりでカウントをクリアしたいと思っています。
遅いクロックでのカウントクリアはあくまでも立ち上がりであるため、リセットのように
入っている間クリアではありません。

下記の記述では論理合成が出来ません。

```
reg [31:0] count;

always @(posedge Clock1, negedge res_n)
begin
    if (~res_n) begin
        count = 0;
    end
    else begin
        count <= count+1;
    end
end
always @(posedge Clock2)
begin
    count <= 0;
end
```

また、下記の記述ではClocl2がHighの時に常にクリアされてしまいます。

```
reg [31:0] count;

always @(posedge Clock1, posedge Clock2)
begin
    if (Clock2) begin
        count = 0;
    end
    else begin
        count <= count+1;
    end
end
```

どのように記述するのは正しいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

新たに clear_done という変数を用意して、

- Clock2 が立ち上がった時は count を0にして、clear_done フラグを立てる
- Clock2 が立ち上がっても、clear_done ならばクリアしない
- Clock2 が立ち下がった時に clear_done フラグを下ろす

という方法で Clock2 の立ち上がりのタイミングだけ count をクリアする方法ではどうでしょうか。

```
reg [31:0] count = 0;
reg clear_done = 0;

always @(posedge Clock1, posedge Clock2, negedge Clock2, negedge res_n)
begin
    if (~Clock2 && clear_done) begin
        clear_done <= 0;
    end
    if (Clock2 && ~clear_done) begin
        count <= 0;
        clear_done <= 1;
    end
    else if (~res_n) begin
        count <= 0;
    end
    else begin
        count <= count + 1;
    end
end
```

手元に論理合成できる環境がないので、動かなかったら済みません。

Comment: 残念ながら、別のalwaysの中にclear_flag等の同じレジスターがあると論理合成出来ないみたいです。

Comment: すみません。先ほどの回答は間違いだったので書き直しました。

Comment: 残念ながらアルテラ MAX10ではエラーとなるようです。
おそらく立ち上がりエッジと立ち下がりエッジを同時に記述することが出来ない用です。
下記のエラーメッセージが出ます。
event control cannot test for both positive and negative edges of variable "Clock2"

Answer (score 2):

いろいろ試していたら、なんとか出来るようになりました。
ありがとうございました。
ソースコードをのせておきます。

```
reg oldClock2;

always @(posedge Clock, posedge Clock2, negedge res_n)
begin
    if (~res_n) begin
        count <= 0;
        oldClock2 <= 0;
    end
    else begin
        if (Clock2) begin
            if (~oldClock2) begin
                count <= 0;
                Clock2 <= 1;
            end
            else begin
                count <= count+1;
            end
        end
        else begin
            count <= count+1;
            if (~Clock2) begin
                oldClock2 <= 0;
            end
        end
    end
end
```